# How to inspect the types of a function's parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, parameter-passing

I have an application where I'm building a function, `marshal_and_apply`, which calls some other function (or functor), `f` with some arguments. `marshal_and_apply`'s job is to apply some special marshaling for the arguments depending on the type of `f`'s parameters.

If one of `f`'s parameters is of a special type, `marshal_me<T>`, then `marshal_and_apply` will marshal the parameter through some specially allocated storage before passing it to `f`. In order to perform the allocation, the storage requirements of all the parameters must be known to `marshal_and_apply` before any can be marshaled.

---

Some examples:

```
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void marshal_and_apply(Function f, Args... args);

void func1(int x, int y);
void func2(marshal_me<int> x, int y);
void func3(marshal_me<int> x, marshal_me<int> y, marshal_me<int> z);

// this call would be equivalent to:
// func1(7,13)
marshal_and_apply(func1, 7, 13);

// this call would be equivalent to:
// auto storage = my_allocator(sizeof(int));
// auto x = marshal_me<int>(7, storage);
// func2(x, 13);
marshal_and_apply(func2, 7, 13);

// this call would be equivalent to:
// auto storage = my_allocator(sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));
// auto x = marshal_me<int>(7, storage);
// auto y = marshal_me<int>(13, storage + sizeof(int));
// auto z = marshal_me<int>(42, storage + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));
// func3(x,y,z);
marshal_and_apply(func3, 7, 13, 42);
```

---

To solve this problem, it seems that `marshal_and_apply` requires a mechanism to inspect the types of `f`'s parameters. I suspect this isn't possible in general, but it may be possible to recognize whether one of a special set of types (in this case, `marshal_me<T>`) is convertible to the type of a particular parameter.

How should I build `marshal_and_apply`?

Comment: In your second example, I can't see what you've done with the `7`. Did you mean `auto x = marshal_me<int>(storage, 7);` or something?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yes, I've corrected it.

Comment: If `marshal_me<int>` has a constructor taking `int` you can call `func2(7, 13)` anyway.  What additional benefit is the wrapper?

Comment: @BenJackson The example is contrived. The full explanation is beyond the scope of this post, but I need to allocate memory for function parameters in a particular way due to the unusual requirements of GPU programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void marshal_and_apply(Function f, Args &&... args)
{
    f(InspectAndModify<Args>::process(sizeof...(Args), std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

Now define:

```
template <typename T> struct InspectAndModify
{
    static T&& process(unsigned int N, T && t)
    {
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }
};

template <typename T> struct InspectAndModify<marshal_me<T>>
{
     static T&& process(unsigned int N, marshal_me<T> && m)
     {
         /* ... */
     }
};
```

---

**Something completely different:** This approach first dissects the function signature, and then performs a "static transform" on each pair of types, which is where you can insert the `marshal_me` specialization:

```
template <typename T> struct marshal_me { marshal_me(T) { } };

template <typename To, typename From> struct static_transform;

template <typename T> struct static_transform<T, T>
{
  static T go(T t) { return t; }
};

template <typename T> struct static_transform<T, T&>
{
  static T go(T & t) { return t; }
};

template <typename T> struct static_transform<marshal_me<T>, T>
{
  static marshal_me<T> go(T && t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct marshal_impl
{
  template <typename ...Urgs>
  static T go(T(*f)(Urgs...), Args &&... args)
  {
    return f(static_transform<Urgs, Args>::go(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
  }
};

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void marshal_and_apply(Function f, Args &&... args)
{
  marshal_impl<void, Args...>::go(static_cast<typename std::decay<Function>::type>(f),
                                  std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That will sort of work, but I'm afraid it wouldn't solve the third example. ```InspectAndModify::process``` needs to know the total number of parameters it needs to process before it can process any of them.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: can you pass `sizeof...(Args)` as an additional parameter?

Comment: To which function? The signature of ```marshal_and_apply``` is fixed, but it could pass extra info to ```InspectAndModify::process```.

Comment: Updated - I'm passing the total size to `process` now.

Comment: Got it; I should have been more specific. The problem is that ```marshal_and_apply``` does not receive ```marshal_me``` objects as parameters -- it just receives ```int```s, for example. So in your code, ```process``` would never receive a ```marshal_me```, and that specialization would never be instantiated.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: ohh, sorry, I misunderstood! Basically you want to discriminate based on the *signature* of `Function`?

Comment: Exactly, modulo the fact that functors could have overloaded ```operator()``` with different numbers of parameters.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: OK, I'm trying something new. It's still pretty broken, but let's see how far we get. Centrepiece of the magic is the `static_transform` template.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Alright, I think it's fairly workable now -- give it a try!

Comment: +1 for `static_cast<typename std::decay<Function>::type>(f)` alone

Comment: The ```T(*f)(Urgs...)``` bit looks like exactly what I would need to inspect the function signature. I've come up with a different approach for inspecting function objects. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Yeah, my version only works for function pointers. You'd really want something that matches all "callable entities"...