# Determine which overload will be called when passing type as reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overload-resolution

I have free functions `foo` which are overloaded for user defined types `X` as follows (`C` being a library type calling `foo`):

```
template <typename C>
void foo(C&, const X&) {...}
```

I am able to determine at compile-time whether there exists an overload for a specific type `X`:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto foo_exists(int) -> decltype(std::bind<void(*)(Args...)>(&foo, std::declval<Args>()...), std::true_type());

template <typename... Args>
auto foo_exists(char) -> std::false_type;

struct Caller
{
    template <typename T>
    void call(const T& x)
    {
        static_assert(decltype(foo_exists<decltype(*this), const T&>(0))::value, "");
    }
};
```

Now assume the following class hierarchy with `foo` overloads for `Base` and `Derived`:

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived : Base {};
struct Leaf : Derived{};

template <typename C>
void foo(C&, const Base&) { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }

template <typename C>
void foo(C&, const Derived&) { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
```

**How can I determine that when invoking `foo(..., Leaf())`, the `const Derived&` overload will be called?**

*Generically speaking:*

I want to test for the exact type of `foo` in order to find out whether a function overload for a specific type `X`. exists; if it does not exist, I want to know if other function overloads for a base types of `X` exist and if yes, which one would be called when passing an argument of type `const X&` to it.

The "which" information should contain the base type, which for the above example would be `Derived` (and not `Base`).

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b680c06fd9da8630)</kbd>

Comment: @ildjarn I read that other question, however I thought that maybe my restriction to base-class overloads would enable what I need

Comment: The fundamental limitation is the lack of compile-time introspection for overload sets; the types being used as arguments have no bearing AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the function signatures and write a custom trait to detect which one will be called, like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
    static Base mock_foo(const Base&);
    static Derived mock_foo(const Derived&);
    static void mock_foo(...);

    // Base if Base overload will be called, Derived if Derived overload
    // will be called, void if neither
    using type = decltype(mock_foo(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72655b770becc15

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this "automatically", *i.e.,* without typing out a custom trait this way. I would guess that the answer is no, it would require some sort of reflection support in the core language.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot enumerate all signatures in my library as the overloads of `foo` are user-defined

Comment: @m.s. I doubt it is possible to implement such a trait without language support then. But let's see if someone proves me wrong.

Comment: I fear you are right, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561453/determining-which-overload-was-selected I thought that maybe my restriction to base-class overloads would enable this